# How to get a value from a combobox in javascript

Tags: javascript, spiceworks

I have this function and I want to make the `var` category to have the value of the combobox that has the id `#ticket_category_clone`

What am I doing wrong?

```
   function check () {
      var category="#ticket_category_clone";
          if (category=="Hardware")
      {
      SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('#ticket_c_hardware_clone{display: none !important;}');
      }
    }

    SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(check);​
```

edit

It only alerts if I make the code this way:

```
function check () {
    // var category = document.getElementById('#ticket_c_hardware_clone').value;
   var category ="Hardware";
   alert(category)
          if (category=="Hardware")
      {
        SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('#ticket_c_hardware_clone{display: none !important;}');


      }
   alert(category)
    }

SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(check);
```

​

like this? http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8438/semttuloluu.png

and the code:

```
<select id="ticket_category_clone" name="ticket[category]" hdpp="ticket_category"><option value=""></option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno about spiceworks but in JavaScript that's how you can do that:

```
var category = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone").value;
```

If the `#` is part of the id, add it as well but note it's not valid ID:

```
var category = document.getElementById("#ticket_category_clone").value;
```

Looks like you need some debugging. Try the following code:

```
var category = "";
var ddl = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone");
if (ddl) {
    alert("found (1)");
    category = ddl.value;
} else {
    ddl = document.getElementById("#ticket_category_clone");
    if (ddl) {
        alert("found (2)");
        category = ddl.value;
    } else {
        alert("element can't be found");
    }
}
alert(category);
```

What alerts you get?

Comment: the value can be a text or numbers or threes not problem with that?

Comment: The type will always be string (text) so to treat it differently you'll have to convert. For example to treat it as number use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: the value of the combobox its always a text so theres no problem with that ?

Comment: No, there should be no problems.

Comment: then theres some thing else wrong because it not doing anything

Comment: To make sure it has correct value add `alert(category)` to the code - do you see the proper value?

Comment: Can you post the HTML source? You need to find the actual and real id of the element.

Comment: I fear it means the drop down is not part of the current document. Add this to your function: `alert("found " + document.getElementsByTagName("select").length + " drop downs");` what you see?

Comment: So it's Spiceworks issue after all - you need some way to access the actual document. You might have more luck in [their official forums](http://community.spiceworks.com)

Comment: if i get here the code of the plugin that makes those subs it may help?

Comment: No man sorry - reverse engineering the framework doesn't sound like valid option. Sorry for not spotting this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test with this lines?

```
var e = document.getElementById(""#ticket_category_clone");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

`alert(str)`, if you get the value you want?

Answer (score 0):

This addition is probably late but if someone stumble on this they should know that SpiceWorks uses prototype.js as the JavaScript library. Therefore to get an element in the DOM you use the $ sign

So in order to get the combobox you use the following syntax

```
var e = $("#ticket_category_clone");
var category = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```